# How can I stop all my SWIFTUI buttons toggling together?

Tags: swift, button, swiftui

I want to create a grid of square buttons that I can click/tap to toggle between black and white.
As a half-way point I am creating a row of buttons that do this - see code below.
But when I click on one of them all the buttons toggle together.
I can't see why this is because I have a state variable for each Cell?

```
struct ContentView: View {
  var body: some View {
    ZStack {
      Color.green
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
      RowOfCellsView(string: "X.X.X.X")
    }
  }
}

struct Cell: Identifiable {
  var id: Int
  var state: Bool
}

struct RowOfCellsView: View {
  var string: String
  var cells: [Cell] {
    string.map { Cell(id: 1, state: $0 == ".") }
  }

  var body: some View {
    HStack {
      ForEach(cells) { cell in
        CellView(isBlack: cell.state, symbol: "Q")
      }
    }
  }
}

struct CellView: View {
  @State var isBlack: Bool
  @State var symbol: String

  var body: some View {
    Button(action: { self.isBlack.toggle() }) {
      Text("")
        .font(.largeTitle)
        .frame(width: 40, height: 40)
        .aspectRatio(1, contentMode: .fill)
    }
    .background(isBlack ? Color.black : Color.white)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Aha - just noticed that I have the id set to 1 for all Cells - that's the problem!
So needs to have a way to have a different id for each Cell.

For example could do:

```
string.enumerated().map { Cell(id: $0.0, state: $0.1 == ".") }
```